flutter y firebase
hola estoy trabajando en visual studio code conectando firebase con flutter (android) al momento de querer pegar algunas lienas de codigo que me marca la pagina de firebase las cuales me pide que pegue a nivel proyecto y app (build.gradle) no me sale la parte de  dependicies y esto es lo unico que me sale :
nivel proyecto

nivel app:


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No te sale que cosa en donde???
